# How can update and refresh every single row in a ajax loaded div?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am facing difficulties to update and automatically refresh my table row using jQuery in a AJAX loaded div.
Code to load data in a div after select a value from select option: AJAX part

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showUser2(str)
  {
    <!-- code -->
  }
  </script>
```

Select option part:

```
<select name ='country_select' onchange='showUser2(this.value)'>
  <!-- options -->
</select>
```

Loaded DIV with list of all users for selected country:

```
<div id='txtHint'></div>
```

DIV contains:

Header:

User Name   Delete User     Change Status

Data:

Ben     Delete icon     Status icon

Max     Delete icon     Status icon

Code:

```
<div id="otherdiv">
 <!-- Delete/ Enable user -->
<ul>
 <li>
  <?php echo $data[user_name]; ?>
 </li> 
 <li>
  <a href="#" id="<?php echo $data[training_id]; ?>" class="delete_button">X</a>
 </li>
 <li>
   <a href="#" id="<?php echo $data[training_id]; ?>" class="deassign_training">
    <img src='images/on.png' style='border:0;'/>
   </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

```
 <!-- Delete/Disable user -->
<ul>
 <li>
  <?php echo $data[user_name]; ?>
 </li>  
 <li>               
  <a href="#" id="<?php echo $data[training_id]; ?>" class="delete_button">X</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#" id="<?php echo $data[training_id]; ?>" class="assign_training">
   <img src='images/off.png' style='border:0;'/>
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

when I click on image icon to delete/enable/disable user then it didn't work. Here is the  code for delete user:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
  $(".delete_button").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
  var parent = $(this).parent();

  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "deleteajax.php",
     data: dataString,
     cache: false,

    success: function(data)
    {
      $("#otherdiv").load("index.php");
    }

   });

  return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Following code for enable/disable user:

```
$(function()
  {
    $(".assign_training").click(function() 
    {
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
      var parent = $(this).parent();

      $.ajax(
      {
        type: "POST",
        url: "assign.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,

        success: function(data)
        { 
          $("#otherdiv").load("index.php");
        }

      });
      return false;
    });

    $(".deassign_training").click(function() 
    {
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
      var parent = $(this).parent();

      $.ajax(
      {
        type: "POST",
        url: "deassign.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,

        success: function(data)
        {
          $("#otherdiv").load("index.php");
        }

      });

      return false;
    });

  });
```

I am not sure why its working after select a country name. I already tried so many techniques from Stack Overflow and other so many website but finally its not working. Its working only if user details loaded directly on the page.

I hope I will found a helpful answer.

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend reducing the amount of code in your question and isolating the problem. If you are able to reproduce the problem in http://jsfiddle.net, even better!

Comment: Whats not working? Are you saying that `assign-training`, `deassign-training` and `delete_button` stop working after loading the new content?

Comment: Yes, when click on to update or delete user then its not working. It was working before but then its loaded whole page in otherdiv.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see you are initiating delete/enable/disable events before DOM creation.
Try to change these blocks:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    <!-- YOUR CODE HERE -->
  });
</script>
```

to:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    <!-- YOUR CODE HERE -->
  });
</script>
```

This should help